# How to send files using Smack?

Tags: gmail, smack

I am struggling with this code:

```
FileTransferManager manager = new FileTransferManager(connection)

OutgoingFileTransfer transfer = manager.createOutgoingFileTransfer("gmailusername@gmail/Smack");


try { 
  System.out.println("000"); 
  transfer.sendFile(new File("D:/cow.wav"), "Moo !"); 
  System.out.println("111"); 

  while(!transfer.isDone()) { 
    System.out.println(transfer.getProgress() + " is done!");    
    //System.out.println(transfer.getStreamID() + " is done!"); 

    try { 
      Thread.sleep(1000); 
    } 
    catch (InterruptedException e) { 
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block e.printStackTrace(); 
    }
  } 
} 
catch (XMPPException e) { 
  // TODO Auto-generated catch block e.printStackTrace(); 
}
```

It seams that it can't send the file.

Can anyone help me solve this problem ?

Answer (score 2):

I believe Gmail (judging from your code above) does not support file transfer. See [this](http://developer.pidgin.im/wiki/Protocol%20Specific%20Questions#Miscellaneous). You can also send a `disco#item` and `disco#info` to see if it supports any kind of byte stream proxy. However some servers like `jabber.org` does not return any `disco#info` on proxies.

For querying XMPP services see my [blog](http://oneminutedistraction.wordpress.com/2010/07/29/making-sense-of-the-serivces/).

Answer (score 0):

You haven't entered the complete id of receiver. Retrieve it using

```
myRoster.getRoster().getPresence(entry).getFrom()
```

Then, make the transfer and ensure that recieiver is the one using XMPP and also doesn't use gtalk because its file transfer is different from XMPP.

Answer (score 0):

We discovered that SMACK tends to add the "/smack" application specifier after login.  If you use the above techniques you should see this happening.  Oddly this doesn't affect messages but does affect file transfer